# How to make elements behave like table aligned

Tags: html, css

I need to align the spans. Problem is on mobile devices, where they divide into two columns with two cells each. The last in the rightmost column is all to the left towards the other. The first row align perfectly. How can I fix this?

```
<div id="topbar" style="background-color:#355A73; color:white;">
    <div class="col-full">
        <span style="display:inline-block;"><div class="tooltip"><i class="far fa-clock" style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px;"></i>SOme text<span class="tooltiptext"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right" style="color:white;margin-right:5px;"></i>Some text</span>
        <span style="display:inline-block;"><div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-lock" style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px;"></i> Some Text <span class="tooltiptext"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right" style="color:white;margin-right:5px;"></i>Some Text</span></div></span>
        <span style="display:inline-block;"><div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px; "></i>Some Text <span class="tooltiptext"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right" style="color:white;margin-right:5px;"></i>Some Text</span>
        <span style="display:inline-block;"><div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-money-bill" style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px;"></i>Some Text<span class="tooltiptext"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right" style="color:white;margin-right:5px;"></i>Some Text</span></div></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Site is [quickdiagnostics.co.uk](http://quickdiagnostics.co.uk)

Comment: Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: avoid inline css / js at all costs - its bad practice that leads to hard-to maintain code

Comment: Can you provide an example using the button that says snippet? (7th button from the left if you edit your question if I'm correct).

Comment: can you please send me a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: Thanks ThisGuyHaveTwoThumbs - that's learned the hard way

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
    </div>
</div>
```

`display: table;` => For parent div.

`display: table-cell;` => For child div

Comment: One might want to use tables instead of `display:table`, I doubt this is the answer though. Also, avoid style tags if you can. It will spoil your codebase eventually.

Comment: can you please send me a screenshot of your problem

Comment: How do I send pictures?

Comment: Edit your question, there is an option to add photo.